# Adding fields to shapefile from standalone PyQGIS script?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

When I run the following script via OSGEO4W64 Shell, I receive the following error when trying to run the `qgis:fieldcalculator` algorithm:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mapCanvas'

I read that the error message relates to the script trying to access an interface although I'm not sure. The algorithm does what it's supposed to with the output layer containing a new `ID` column, but the layer has no features saved.

Basically, I would like to add a new `ID` field using the formula `$rownum` and remove the `longitude` and `latitude` fields which are generated by the *Create grid* algorithm. I would also be happy if this can be achieved without having to use the *Field calculator* algorithm (ie. by directly accessing the data).

```
import os, sys, glob

from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
app = QApplication([])
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

from os.path import expanduser
home = expanduser("~")

#   Folder path of the Results for shapefiles
path_dir = home + "\Desktop\Test\\"
path_res = path_dir + "Results\\"

# Prepare processing framework 
sys.path.append( home + '\.qgis2\python\plugins' )
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
from processing.tools import *

def run():

    outputs_1=general.runalg("qgis:creategrid", 1000, 1000, 24108, 18351.157175, 258293.802316, 665638.226408, 1, 'EPSG:7405', None)
    outputs_2=general.runalg("qgis:fieldcalculator", outputs_1['SAVENAME'], 'ID', 1, 10, 0, True, '$rownum', None)
    outputs_3=processing.runalg("qgis:deletecolumn", outputs_2['OUTPUT_LAYER'], 'longitude', None)
    outputs_4=processing.runalg("qgis:deletecolumn", outputs_3['SAVENAME'], 'latitude', path_res  + "/" + "grid.shp")

#   Paths of the shapefiles in the Result folder with list comprehension
    output = [shp for shp in glob.glob(path_res + "*.shp")]

run()
QgsApplication.exitQgis()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm you are running requires some references to common QGIS components, which are available to plugins via an iface ([QgisInterface](http://qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html)) object. In this case you need a custom iface object because i) there is no QGIS instance running, ii) you are running a plugin, and iii) the algorithm you are running requires access to QGIS components (e.g. map canvas).

You can emulate the iface object by yourself, but thankfully [my custom iface is included in Processing](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/tests/qgis_interface.py), so we can use it.

However, because of some changes to QgisInterface in the official QGIS project, you would need to either i) edit the file `.../plugins/processing/tests/qgis_interface.py` to make it equivalent to [this one](http://downloads.tuxfamily.org/tuxgis/otros/qgis_interface.py), or ii) download the file and replace the existing one. I've just changed 5 lines.

This is the working script:

```
import os, sys, glob

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvas
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
app = QApplication([])
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

from os.path import expanduser
home = expanduser("~")

#   Folder path of the Results for shapefiles
path_dir = home + "/Test/"
path_res = path_dir + "/Results"

# Prepare processing framework 
sys.path.append( home + '/.qgis2/python/plugins' )

# Get an iface object
canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
from processing.tests.qgis_interface import QgisInterface
iface = QgisInterface( canvas )

# Initialize the Processing plugin passing an iface object
from processing.ProcessingPlugin import ProcessingPlugin
plugin = ProcessingPlugin(iface)
from processing.tools import *

def run():

    outputs_1=general.runalg("qgis:creategrid", 1000, 1000, 24108, 18351.157175, 258293.802316, 665638.226408, 1, 'EPSG:7405', None)
    outputs_2=general.runalg("qgis:fieldcalculator", outputs_1['SAVENAME'], 'ID', 1, 10, 0, True, '$rownum', path_res  + "/" + "grid.shp")
    outputs_3=general.runalg("qgis:deletecolumn", outputs_2['OUTPUT_LAYER'], 'longitude', None)
    outputs_4=general.runalg("qgis:deletecolumn", outputs_3['SAVENAME'], 'latitude', path_res  + "/" + "grid.shp")

#   Paths of the shapefiles in the Result folder with list comprehension
    output = [shp for shp in glob.glob(path_res + "*.shp")]

run()
QgsApplication.exitQgis()
app.exit()
```

I tested it on GNU/Linux succesfully.

Comment: Many thanks @gcarrillo. When I run this, I receive several messages (nothing about errors) but it crashes my python.exe. I will keep trying but I edited my question to include that I don't mind if the _Field Calculator_ algorithm is not used as I only want to add a new field to the grid and remove 2 other fields. It would be equally great if there's another way to do this without having to use the _Field Calculator_.

Comment: I've edited my answer with some important changes. Please test it on your environment. It shouldn't crash your python this time.

Comment: Again thank you, python no longer crashes! I do receive one error: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`. I downloaded and replaced the qgis_interface.py file with yours.

Comment: Probably should have mentioned that it's for line 35 beginning with `outputs_4=...`

Comment: Bingo! I had to change the `QgsApplication.setPrefixPath` to match my own as I'm guessing the one in your script is for Linux. I now have the output shapefile I require! One little thing is that an error shows up: _QGraphicsScene::addItem: item has already been added to this scene. ERROR 4: `data/raster' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognised as a supported dataset name._ Any ideas? Otherwise, many thanks for your help @gcarrillo :)

Comment: Great! Always make sure paths are set properly. Regarding the 'data/raster' error, it occurs because the QgisInterface that is in processing (not the original I wrote) loads a raster from 'data/raster' for testing purposes. You have 2 options to avoid the error: i) Copy the file `processing/tests/data/raster.tif` to `your_script_path + '/data/' + 'raster'`, or ii) Take the `processing/tests/qgis_interface.py` script, move it to your script folder, modify it removing the code that uses test data, since it's not necessary for your purposes, and adjust the import. I would choose ii).

Comment: Excellent tips buddy! Yes, I have to remember to keep checking that the paths remain consistent. You're right, I also think option ii) would be much more convenient so will test that out. Thank you very much again!